# Unable to process concurrent requests due to server sleep before closing socket

Tags: linux, windows, tcp

This is a simple TCP server program.

The server has a total of five child processes, all of which do the same job: sending the current timestamp to the client and then sleep for five seconds ,then it wait for the next request.

The program seems to work fine, but when I swap lines 108 and 109, that is, sleep before closing the socket, the program will not be able to concurrency.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MSG_TYPE "%ld\n"
#define SPORT 2023

static int sfd;

void server_job();

int main()
{
    sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sfd < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(-1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port = htons(SPORT);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "0.0.0.0", &saddr.sin_addr);

    int val = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &val, sizeof(val)) < 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        close(sfd);
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (bind(sfd, (void *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        close(sfd);
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (listen(sfd, 100) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        close(sfd);
        exit(-1);
    }

    struct sigaction new_sa, sa_save;
    new_sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    new_sa.sa_flags = SA_NOCLDWAIT;
    sigemptyset(&new_sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGCLD, &new_sa, &sa_save);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
        {
            perror("fork");
            exit(-1);
        }
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            server_job();
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    pause();

    close(sfd);
}

void server_job()
{
    struct sockaddr_in caddr;
    socklen_t caddr_len = sizeof(caddr);
    FILE *fp;

    while (1)
    {
        int connfd = accept(sfd, (void *)&caddr, &caddr_len);
        if (connfd < 0)
        {
            if (errno == EINTR || errno == EAGAIN)
                continue;
            perror("accept");
            exit(-1);
        }

        fp = fdopen(connfd, "r+");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            perror("fdopen");
            close(sfd);
            exit(-1);
        }
        fprintf(fp, MSG_TYPE, time(NULL));

        fclose(fp); //---------here-----
        sleep(5);   //---------here------
    }

    close(sfd);
}
```

Comment: The program is fairly big. I get errors and warnings when I try to compile it. Try to create a [mre] and add an explanation how it is supposed to work.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. I have made changes to the original problem.